# The onclick remove affecting other button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function for delete button (to delete based on what i click) and it is working, but when i clicked on other button it does the delete function which
is not supposed to do. how can i prevent affecting the other button?

```
function myDelete()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
        $(this).remove();
        var sum = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: how is `myDelete` called?

Comment: The problem is you are binding the handler to the doucment object

Comment: You can change the class of the document. as for now it is deleting the .item class.

Answer (score 1):

You would better bind your 'click' event to the particular dom object, rather than to the document object.

Please try this code :

```
function myDelete()
{
    $('.item').on('click', function(){
        $(this).remove();
        var sum = 0;
    });
}
```

Also, it looks weird to me that you have to wrap this in a function. A simple wrapper (equivalent of "on dom load") should be enough in most cases :

```
$(function(){
  // you code here such as :
  $('.item').on('click', function(){
      $(this).remove();
      var sum = 0;
  });
});
```

Comment: you may also use `$('.item').click(function(){ ... });` as it is easier to write, imho

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put your function inside `$(document).ready()`. For deleting clicked button, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(functio(){
      $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
         $(this).remove();
         var sum = 0;
   });

});
```

Or, you can do this:

```
<button class="item" onclick="myDelete(this)">Button</button>

function myDelete(element)
{
    $(element).remove();
    var sum = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just bind your click event with the class assosiates with it. No need to wrap it with other function.

```
$('.item').on('click', function(){
    $(this).remove();
    var sum = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="item">Other Button</button>

<button onclick="myDelete(this)">Button</button>

function myDelete()
{
    $('.item').remove();
    var sum = 0;
}
```